# SQL Server pre-login request - driver usage

Tags: sql-server, wireshark

What specific driver's version is being sent to SQL Server during “TDS7 pre-login request” from client (terminal server) towards SQL Server to establish connection in SSMS

[image: Below is the TDS request shown in bits.]

After conversion I got version 4.7.3630 checked ODBC drivers x86/x64 but no such version is installed so either I am converting it incorrectly or the value is for a different client's driver.

“TDS7 pre-login response” coming from SQL Server towards client matches nicely.

Comment: SSMS uses SqlClient rather than ODBC.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Dan Guzman, I was able to identify the driver by checking what libraries SSMS uses, where System.Data contained System.Data.SqlClient which indeed was of 4.7.3630 version